# Queue of defined type implementation in C

Tags: c, queue, hashtable

I am trying to find an implementation of a queue to use it to hold processes that are of type GDB. I have been looking all over the place and whatever I use I get an incompatible type when i try to enqueue the process of type GDB in the queue. Anyone knows an implementation of a queue that I can use or Hash_table ?

Comment: queuing processes? huh? *shakes head*

Comment: @Marc yeah im trying to code up a small operating system

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any general-purpose queue worth using (including one you could roll on your own) should allow you to store `void *`, no questions asked.

So you should only store the address of whatever "process of type GDB" means.

Comment: it says when I do so that 'passing argument 1 of Enqueue makes integer from pointer without a cast' do you know any general-purpose queue worth using?

Comment: I used this queue implementation http://www.idevelopment.info/data/Programming/data_structures/c/Queue/Queue.shtml

Answer (score 0):

I use [this one](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.29/glib-Hash-Tables.html), serves me fine.

Comment: how can I use it? do I have to download the hole glib library?

Comment: @biz: It ships on pretty on much every Linux installation. Consider it a standard system library. If that's a problem, link against it statically, and it'll only pull in the stuff you use.

Comment: what if I use Mac Os? I am not sure I understand what you mean link to it statically?

Comment: Static linking includes the statically linked library's code within the final binary. This means you won't require the library in the form of a shared/dynamic library at run time.